# Htaccess - replacing a query string with a numeric value

Tags: htaccess, php, apache, mod-rewrite

I don't know why but this htaccess item doesn't work for me.
I have something like this after update user profile `public/user_profile/show_user.html?id=4` and I want to have  `public/user_profile/show_user.html/4`

1. **htaccess**

`RewriteRule ^show_user.html/(\d+)$ show_user.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

2. **profile.php**

   After update user -> redirect to user detail

`redirect_to(url_for('/user_profile/show_user.html/' . $id));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to have `public/user_profile/show_user.html/4`
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^show_user.html/(\d+)$ show_user.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

Assuming `public/` is the document root and this `.htaccess` file is in the document root then you are missing `/user_profile` from the start of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^user_profile/show_user\.html/(\d+)$ show_user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Don't forget to backslash escape literal dots. You shouldn't need the `NC` flag here.

This directive also needs to be near the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* any front-controller. Order matters.

Comment: Of course I'm in a different place :)  As always, thanks for your help MrWhite:)